# Exporting utility functions from multiple files

Tags: javascript, typescript, module

I recently came across several files in a typescript/javascript codebase that are re-exporting utilities from other files. I came across it because my IDE didn't detect the function references when they were being re-exported. Initially my IDE said there were about 20 references but it looks like there are possibly 10x that as I find the files re-exporting one runtime error at a time.

The purpose seems clear, so the individual could take a dozen different utilities and * import them from one file.  While this seems like a questionable practice I was curious if there are other reasons for or against doing this.

a folder might contain a file at the top level like:

```
export { fiz } from 'somefile'
export { baz } from 'someotherfile'

export const buz = ...
```

usage:

```
import * as funcs from ...

funcs.fiz()
funcs.baz()
funcs.buz()
```

Comment: One of the pros is to just import an index file by indicating a folder name only. That way you don't need to import individual files and you don't need to know the structure of this folder (it can contain several levels of subfolders, for instance). And that way you can have one imported entry point which means at least it would be more easily manageable.

Comment: This would make sense to me if there was just one folder to import but the way it has been set up is each component has its own utils folder so each component is importing a different file that has the same functions being re-exported. so fiz and baz are being exported from dozens of files.